# piping the put request to stream file upload to Google Cloud Storage using "got" always fails "403"

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, node.js-got

I'm trying to stream file upload to google cloud storage bucket,
through signed url,
I'm using "got" to pipe the request, but the request always fails gibing me 403, access denied and signature mismatch.

my code:

```
save(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const gotStream = got.stream.put(signedUrl, {
        headers: req.headers,

        // for local machine
        https: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
    });

    req.pipe(gotStream);

    // Handling response and errors
    gotStream.on('data', (response) => {
        if (response.statusCode === 200) {
            res.json({ success: true });
        } else {
            res.status(response.statusCode).send('Upload to GCS failed');
        }
    });

    gotStream.on('error', (error) => {
        res.status(500).send(error.message); // 'Error during streaming upload'
    });
}
```

although the same request succeed in postman for the asme "signedUrl"

I've tried changing put request and sign the url action as resumable with no luck